# How to add leading zeros in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a question about SQL Server: how to add leading three 000 (zeros) while id does not have leading zeros in SQL Server?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ids]
(
     [id] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
     [name] [VARCHAR](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ids] ([id], [name]) VALUES (N'09', N'abc')
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ids] ([id], [name]) 
VALUES (N'0098', N'de'), (N'987', N'j'), (N'00056', N'i'),
       (N'6', N'z'), (N'0908', N'u'),
       (N'99999999', N'u'), (N'7522323838483', N'i')
GO
```

Based on above data I want output like below :

```
name    | id
--------+-----------
abc     | 0009
de      | 00098
j       | 000987
i       | 00056
z       | 0006
u       | 000908
u       | 00099999999
i       | 0007522323838483
```

I tried like this:

```
SELECT 
    RIGHT('000' + id, 3) id, [name]
FROM 
    [dbo].[ids]
```

but above query is not returning the expected result.

Can you please tell me how to write a query to achieve this task in SQL Server?

Comment: I think you just need to remove the `RIGHT`: `'000' + id`

Comment: @gbalu take some time and read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers/251399#251399

Answer (score 4):

You could try stripping leading zeroes, then concatenating three zeroes to the front, e.g.

```
SELECT
    id,
    '000' + SUBSTRING(id, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', id + '.'), LEN(id)) AS id_out,
    name
FROM ids;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Nice, though this can be simplified using `stuff`, like this: `STUFF(Id, 1, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', id) - 1, '000') AS id_out`

Comment: @ZoharPeled Good `STUFF`, no pun intended `:-P`

Answer (score 1):

Just another thought is to use try_convert() if your ID strings are are numeric

**Example**

```
Select *
      ,NewValue = '000'+left(try_convert(bigint,id),25)
 From  ids
```

Returns

```
id              name    NewValue
09              abc     0009
0098            de      00098
987             j       000987
00056           i       00056
6               z       0006
0908            u       000908
99999999        u       00099999999
7522323838483   i       0007522323838483
```

Comment: But why? That only introduces the possibility (probability?) of a logical (though not an actual) conversion error.

Comment: @SMor A) It is just another approach.  B) I did have the caveat if data was numeric  C) Don't think it warrants a down vote.

Answer (score 1):

You can use format(), with '0' as a custom specifier to do this very simply.

```
select NOPER, FORMAT( NOPER, '000000') as NOPER_formatted
from mytable

NOPER       NOPER_formatted
----------- ------------------------------------
100         000100
101         000101
102         000102
10334       010334
10335       010335
10336       010336
```

For more information see the link below :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings

Comment: cheers for the input, this was what i ended up using